# Downloading multiple filenames with one request? Python

Tags: python, request

```
for v,i in enumerate(assets_files):
    a = requests.get(domain+i).content
    split_filename = i.split('/')
    path = os.path.join(all_folder[4],split_filename[-1])
    with open(path,'wb') as w:
        w.write(a)
        print('Downloaded: ',split_filename[-1],' number: ',v)
```

I don't want my sys admin banning me for multiple connections. Is there a pythonic option to just download a list of files with one request? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you think making more than one connection is problematic? If your admin really has such draconian rules, it's probably better to run the script on a system with less strict rules in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` has a `Session` object for this as explained [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#advanced-usage).

Using the global `requests.get` will not reuse the conection but `session.get` will probably will.

I am saying probably becase there is a limited connection pool which is used under the hood.